# Current direction and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

So using the right hand rule, I understand current is clockwise. Because I read the magnetic field emerges from the north pole, I thought the answer was a, that the north pole is on the top. But the answers for this state it is b, the north pole is on the bottom.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain this to me?

If the north pole is on top, the field lines *through* the loop would point up, not down.

In the image below, the field lines exit from the top and enter through the bottom.  However, in the image you provide, the field lines exit from the bottom and enter through the top.

[image]